# matplotlib polar plot transparency plotted on image

Tags: python, matplotlib

How can I produce a plot of an image file? All the png files I have are the same size and resolution. The `file 2021_01_02-12:58:34_PM-4planet_graphA_master.png` has a track of the planet orbits I wish to superimpose the planet position created as a png transparency on the background image. 
Images:

[image: Image 1]
[image: Image 2]

```
#coding: utf-8
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import ephem
import datetime as dt
from datetime import datetime, date
import time

t_s = time.time()

from matplotlib.pyplot import imread

now = datetime.now()
date = datetime.now()


# First the imports

from astropy.coordinates import SkyCoord
from sunpy.coordinates import get_body_heliographic_stonyhurst
from astropy.time import Time
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.image as mpimg
import numpy as np
import os

save_file = os.path.join('4planet_graph_test.png')


obstime = date

planet_list = ['earth', 'venus', 'mars', 'mercury']

planet_coord = [get_body_heliographic_stonyhurst(this_planet, time=obstime) for this_planet in 

planet_list]

##############################################################################
# Now lets make a plot.

fig = plt.figure()
plt.figure(figsize=(15,15))


image = mpimg.imread('2021_01_02-12:58:34_PM-4planet_graphA_master.png')

ax1 = plt.subplot(1, 1, 1, projection='polar')
ax1.set_theta_zero_location('N')

for this_planet, this_coord in zip(planet_list, planet_coord):
    plt.polar(np.deg2rad(this_coord.lon), this_coord.radius, 'o', label=this_planet, markersize=10)

plt.legend()
plt.title(date)
plt.imshow(image)

if save_file:
    plt.savefig(save_file, transparent=True)
    plt.close(fig)
else:
     plt.show()
```

Comment: What does it currently output?

Comment: it outputs a polar plot with the sun at the center and the 4 inner planets in their orbits

Comment: If you could, please [edit] your answer with a screenshot of the output.

Comment: sorry i forgot to add to get the script to run the line plt.imshow(image) needs commenting out

Comment: Also, please add the image you are trying to superimpose!

Comment: the 2 images are uploaded i am trying to superimposed the transparency on the master image

Comment: would be better to do this with actual lines on your matplotlib plot